# Rotation of 4D vector

Tags: vectors, rotations

In an XYZU coordinate system, there are 6 planes of rotation.
I have the vector: $$[1,1,1,1]$$
I want to rotate it to be aligned with $$[0,0,0,1]$$ by applying rotations in XY, XZ, YZ, XU, YU, and ZU planes.

I believe it only takes rotations in the XU, YU, and ZU planes to achieve this.

Although, I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate these angles.

Any help would be appreciated.

**My Attempt:**

In 3D, If I wanted to rotate [1,1,1] to [0,0,1]
It would take a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in the XZ plane and a rotation of 
$arcsin(1/\sqrt{3})$ in the YZ plane. I was able to figure this out because I can picture things in 3D! But I'm having trouble generalizing this to 4D.
Since the magnitude of [1,1,1,1] is 2, I know that I will need to include "2" instead of a $\sqrt{3}$, but not sure how to perform the vector algebra to generalize to 4D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the angle between any two vectors satisfies
$$
\theta_{v,w} = \arccos \left(\frac{\langle v,w \rangle }{\|v\| \,\|w\|}\right)
$$
where $\langle v,w \rangle$ denotes the "dot-product" of $v$ and $w$.

With that in mind, we can bring $(1,1,1,1)$ to the desired orientation with three rotations as follows:

1. Take $(1,1,1,1) \to (0,\sqrt{2},1,1)$ with a $\pi/4$ rotation in the $XY$-plane
2. Take $(0,\sqrt{2},1,1) \to (0,0,\sqrt{3},1)$.  The angle of this rotation in the $YZ$ plane is $\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{4})$.
3. Take $(0,0,0,\sqrt{3},1) \to (0,0,0,2)$.  The angle of this rotation in the $ZU$ plane is $\arccos(\frac{2}{4}) = \pi/6$.

Comment: Great! This makes a lot more sense on how to think about it. Since rotations about a plane only affect coordinates associated with the directions spanned by that plane, then you can easily determine it using your process above ^

Also, arccos(2/4) = pi/3, and I believe there wouldn't be a "1" added in the numerator of step (2), since you consider the projection onto the plane, right? Since we arent looking for the angle between the vectors but rather the angle between the projection of the first vector onto the plane that the second vector exists on